# Expanding horizontal DIV for language selection

Tags: css, animation

I would like to create an animated div as done so with the search box at www.arsenal.com, but for language selection. Can I get some aid as to how to approach the CSS aspect of this? Basically there should just be an icon of a flag, and when it is clicked on, a horizontal menu would slide out and then collapse when not in focus.

Here is the basic structure

```
<div class="flags">
    <ul>
        <li>flag 1 with image</li>
        <li>flag 2 with image</li>
        <li>flag 3 with image</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without making use of CSS3 transitions, you'll want to use Javascript to achieve this. I would recommend using `jQuery` and the `animate()` function. Simple enough to animate the `width` attribute.

Target the `mousein` and `mouseout` events.

If you wanted to do it with css3 it'd be something like:

HTML

```
<div class="flags">
    <a href="#menu">current flag image</a>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>flag 1 with image</li>
        <li>flag 2 with image</li>
        <li>flag 3 with image</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#menu:target {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    height: auto;
}
```

Please note this is only possible css-only with the `:target` pseudo-class. You can't target  the hover on something and apply a transition to another element, as far as I know. You will need Javascript to add and remove classes to apply the css transition in that case.

As homework you can modify the above to transform `.flags` creating your 'slide out' behavior.

Comment: I see. Is it generally recommended to use jQuery over CSS for animations? Sorry, I'm fairly new to this!

Comment: CSS animations are a new feature to most web browsers. Most of them will work in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10, but anyone on older versions will not see that animation. jQuery animations will work on almost any browser with javascript enabled.